# Kubernetes Private Repo Imagepullbackoff error

Tags: kubernetes

I followed this: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-setup-a-private-docker-registry-with-lke-and-object-storage/

repo works I can push or pull from my local with user/pass. secret docker-registry regcred created and verified again and again.

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment
  namespace: apps
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: privatrepo.ddns.net/hello
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

any help?

here is the pod logs

```
Name:         
Namespace:    apps
Priority:     0
Node:         
Start Time:   Thu, 20 May 2021 14:13:27 +0200
Labels:       app=hello
              pod-template-hash=7d6674fdff
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.2.0.88/32
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.2.0.88
IPs:
  IP:           10.2.0.88
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/
Containers:
  hello:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          privatrepo.ddns.net/hello
    Image ID:       
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-jlt9v (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-jlt9v:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-jlt9v
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   BackOff  24m (x680 over 179m)   kubelet  Back-off pulling image "privatrepo.ddns.net/hello"
  Warning  Failed   4m5s (x767 over 179m)  kubelet  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: Can you post the events from the pod?

Comment: added the pod describe output